# can't generate the correct response using Swagger on PHP

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to generate a response pattern in my API documentation with swagger. I'm sure that anything else is correct except the `@OA\Property(property="professional_ids", type="array"` line, but I'm not sure what is wrong.

My swagger code is:

```
     * @OA\Post(
     * path="professional/create",
     * summary="Create",
     * description="create",
     * operationId="create",
     * tags={"Professional"},
     * security={ {"default": {} }},
     * @OA\RequestBody(
     *  required=true,
     *  description="description",
     *  @OA\JsonContent(
     *      type="object",
     *      required={"name","body","state","body_number"},
     *      @OA\Property(property="name", type="string", example="marx", maxLength=255),
     *      @OA\Property(property="body", type="string", example="crm", maxLength=10),
     *      @OA\Property(property="state", type="string", example="am", maxLength=2),
     *      @OA\Property(property="body_number", type="string", example="123456", maxLength=255),
     *      @OA\Property(property="professional_ids", type="array",
     *          @OA\Items(type="object",
     *              @OA\Property(property="professional_id", type="integer", example="2")
     *              )
     *      )
     *  ),
     * ),
     * @OA\Response(
     *    response=200,
     *    description="Create Data",
     *    @OA\MediaType(
     *       mediaType="application/json",
     *       @OA\Schema(
     *          @OA\Property(property="data", type="object",
     *              @OA\Property(property="health_professional_info", type="object",
     *                  @OA\Property(property="id", type="integer", example="14"),
     *                  @OA\Property(property="name", type="string", example="marx", maxLength=255),
     *                  @OA\Property(property="body", type="string", example="crm", maxLength=10),
     *                  @OA\Property(property="state", type="string", example="am", maxLength=2),
     *                  @OA\Property(property="body_number", type="string", example="123456", maxLength=255),
     *                  @OA\Property(property="professional_ids", type="array",
     *                      @OA\Items(type="object", 
     *                          @OA\Property(property="professional_id", type="integer", example="2")
     *                      ),
     *                      @OA\Items(type="object", 
     *                          @OA\Property(property="professional_id", type="integer", example="8")
     *                      )
     *                  )
     *              )
     *          ),
     *          @OA\Property(property="error", type="null", example="null")
     *      )
     *    )
     * )
     * )
     */
```

and my response sample is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "professional_info": {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "marx",
      "body": "crm",
      "state": "am",
      "body_number": "123456",
      "professional_ids": [
        {
          "professional_id": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "error": null
}
```

but what I need to get is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "professional_info": {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "marx",
      "body": "crm",
      "state": "am",
      "body_number": "123456",
      "professional_ids": [
        {
          "professional_id": 2
        },
        {
          "professional_id": 8
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "error": null
}
```

anyone knows how to correct this?
Thanks in advance ^.^

Comment: Does this help - [How to add multiple example items in swagger-php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46318345/113116)? Basically you need to add an `example` as a sibling of `@OA\Items`.

Comment: tried that, but it dind't work. For some reason, it seems that my swagger can't "see" what I'm writing. I'll go check my version and see if it have some known issue